# Margin for alluvial plot

Tags: r, margin

I use this example

```
library(alluvial)
tit <- as.data.frame(Titanic)

# only two variables: class and survival status
tit2d <- aggregate( Freq ~ Class + Survived, data=tit, sum)

alluvial( tit2d[,1:2], freq=tit2d$Freq, xw=0.0, alpha=0.8,
          gap.width=0.1, col= "steelblue", border="white",
          layer = tit2d$Survived != "Yes" , cex.axis =8)
```

Pay attention I use `cex.axis =8` and  i get
[image]

Axis labels go beyond
I try to use `par(mar=c(10, 10, 10, 10))` but no result
thanks for any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the source code of the `alluvial` function

The function sets `par(mar=c(2,1,1,1))` hard coded so using the `par()` outside doesn't have any effect.

You could change locally the source code of the function to one of 2 options:

1. add an argument *mar_* and pass the margin, and set at the right place `par(mar=mar_)`.
2. just overwrite locally the line to the desired margins

I found the first option more appealing because you can then set the values from outside the function and optimise more easily.

The source code:

```
function (..., freq, col = "gray", border = 0, layer, hide = FALSE, 
    alpha = 0.5, gap.width = 0.05, xw = 0.1, cw = 0.1, blocks = TRUE, 
    ordering = NULL, axis_labels = NULL, cex = par("cex"), cex.axis = par("cex.axis")) 
{
    p <- data.frame(..., freq = freq, col, alpha, border, hide, 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    np <- ncol(p) - 5
    if (!is.null(ordering)) {
        stopifnot(is.list(ordering))
        if (length(ordering) != np) 
            stop("'ordering' argument should have ", np, " components, has ", 
                length(ordering))
    }
    n <- nrow(p)
    if (missing(layer)) {
        layer <- 1:n
    }
    p$layer <- layer
    d <- p[, 1:np, drop = FALSE]
    p <- p[, -c(1:np), drop = FALSE]
    p$freq <- with(p, freq/sum(freq))
    col <- col2rgb(p$col, alpha = TRUE)
    if (!identical(alpha, FALSE)) {
        col["alpha", ] <- p$alpha * 256
    }
    p$col <- apply(col, 2, function(x) do.call(rgb, c(as.list(x), 
        maxColorValue = 256)))
    isch <- sapply(d, is.character)
    d[isch] <- lapply(d[isch], as.factor)
    if (length(blocks) == 1) {
        blocks <- if (!is.na(as.logical(blocks))) {
            rep(blocks, np)
        }
        else if (blocks == "bookends") {
            c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, np - 2), TRUE)
        }
    }
    if (is.null(axis_labels)) {
        axis_labels <- names(d)
    }
    else {
        if (length(axis_labels) != ncol(d)) 
            stop("`axis_labels` should have length ", names(d), 
                ", has ", length(axis_labels))
    }
    getp <- function(i, d, f, w = gap.width) {
        a <- c(i, (1:ncol(d))[-i])
        if (is.null(ordering[[i]])) {
            o <- do.call(order, d[a])
        }
        else {
            d2 <- d
            d2[1] <- ordering[[i]]
            o <- do.call(order, d2[a])
        }
        x <- c(0, cumsum(f[o])) * (1 - w)
        x <- cbind(x[-length(x)], x[-1])
        gap <- cumsum(c(0L, diff(as.numeric(d[o, i])) != 0))
        mx <- max(gap)
        if (mx == 0) 
            mx <- 1
        gap <- gap/mx * w
        (x + gap)[order(o), ]
    }
    dd <- lapply(seq_along(d), getp, d = d, f = p$freq)
    rval <- list(endpoints = dd)
===============================================
===============Need to edit====================
    op <- par(mar = c(2, 1, 1, 1))
===============================================
    plot(NULL, type = "n", xlim = c(1 - cw, np + cw), ylim = c(0, 
        1), xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", xlab = "", 
        ylab = "", frame = FALSE)
    ind <- which(!p$hide)[rev(order(p[!p$hide, ]$layer))]
    for (i in ind) {
        for (j in 1:(np - 1)) {
            xspline(c(j, j, j + xw, j + 1 - xw, j + 1, j + 1, 
                j + 1 - xw, j + xw, j) + rep(c(cw, -cw, cw), 
                c(3, 4, 2)), c(dd[[j]][i, c(1, 2, 2)], rev(dd[[j + 
                1]][i, c(1, 1, 2, 2)]), dd[[j]][i, c(1, 1)]), 
                shape = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), open = FALSE, 
                col = p$col[i], border = p$border[i])
        }
    }
    for (j in seq_along(dd)) {
        ax <- lapply(split(dd[[j]], d[, j]), range)
        if (blocks[j]) {
            for (k in seq_along(ax)) {
                rect(j - cw, ax[[k]][1], j + cw, ax[[k]][2])
            }
        }
        else {
            for (i in ind) {
                x <- j + c(-1, 1) * cw
                y <- t(dd[[j]][c(i, i), ])
                w <- xw * (x[2] - x[1])
                xspline(x = c(x[1], x[1], x[1] + w, x[2] - w, 
                  x[2], x[2], x[2] - w, x[1] + w, x[1]), y = c(y[c(1, 
                  2, 2), 1], y[c(2, 2, 1, 1), 2], y[c(1, 1), 
                  1]), shape = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
                  open = FALSE, col = p$col[i], border = p$border[i])
            }
        }
        for (k in seq_along(ax)) {
            text(j, mean(ax[[k]]), labels = names(ax)[k], cex = cex)
        }
    }
    axis(1, at = rep(c(-cw, cw), ncol(d)) + rep(seq_along(d), 
        each = 2), line = 0.5, col = "white", col.ticks = "black", 
        labels = FALSE)
    axis(1, at = seq_along(d), tick = FALSE, labels = axis_labels, 
        cex.axis = cex.axis)
    par(op)
    invisible(rval)
}
```

I marked where the problem occur as:

**================================================**

**==============Need to edit======================**

**op <- par(mar = c(2, 1, 1, 1))**

**================================================**

After changing the line to `par(mar=c(5, 5, 3, 10))` I got:

[image]

Comment: fantastic desicion!